# Помогите с for. Не получается решить задачу

Tags: java

Решаю задачу.
У вас имеется ﻿NN﻿ грамм серебра, из которого планируется выпускать монеты. Для монеты делается заготовка весом ﻿KK﻿ грамм, после чего из каждой заготовки делаются монеты ﻿MM﻿ грамм каждая (из каждой заготовки — максимально возможное количество). Если от заготовок после этого что-то остается, то материал возвращают к началу производственного цикла и сплавляют с тем, что осталось при изготовлении заготовок. Таким образом, процесс остановится, когда в сплаве останется меньше, чем ﻿KK﻿ грамм серебра.

Напишите программу, которая вычислит, сколько монет выплавится из ﻿NN﻿ грамм серебра.

Формат входных данных

Числа ﻿N, K, M (1 ≤ N, M, K ≤ 200)N,K,M(1≤N,M,K≤200)﻿ вводятся в одну строку через пробел.

Формат выходных данных

Выведите одно число — количество изготовленных монет.

for без инкремента совсем не работает?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = scn.nextInt();
        int K = scn.nextInt();
        int M = scn.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = K; i < N; ) {
                N = N - K;
                if (K > M){
                    K = K - M;
                    count++;
                }else N = N + K;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: `for` без инкремента прекрасно работает -- получается бесконечный цикл, так как без инкремента всегда будет выполняться условие `i < N`.

Comment: значит цикл там не нужен. Какие требования к алгоритму О(1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи больше подходит цикл `while`:

```java
while (N >= K) { // пока масса слитка больше массы заготовки
// ... считать монеты
}
```

Также следует активно применять операции целочисленного деления `/` и нахождения остатка `%`:

- Найти количество заготовок `N / K` и остаток от деления слитка на заготовки `N % K`
- Для каждой заготовки найти количество монет из одной заготовки `K / M` и остаток от деления заготовки на монеты `K % M`,
- Просуммировать все монеты и остатки серебра (`N` при этом изменится)
- Перейти на следующую итерацию цикла.

---

Для условия выхода из цикла *процесс остановится, когда в сплаве останется меньше, чем KK грамм серебра* (т.е. `N < K`), может возникнуть ситуация, когда серебра не хватит на одну заготовку, но из остатка можно было бы выплавить ещё монеты.

---

Вариант кода:

```java
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Масса слитка: ");
int N = scn.nextInt(); // масса слитка
int K = scn.nextInt(); // масса заготовки
int M = scn.nextInt(); // масса монеты
int coins = 0;         // количество монет
while (N >= K) {
    int planchets = N / K; // количество заготовок
    N %= K; // остаток от деления на массу заготовки
    coins += planchets * (K / M);
    N += planchets * (K % M);
}
System.out.println(coins);
```

---

Если можно было бы по условию выплавлять монеты из *остатка* с массой, меньшей массы заготовки `K`, данная задача может быть решена без использования циклов:

```
int coins = N / M; 
N %= M; // остаток от слитка
```

Comment: Да, учебная) Отказался от for, но похоже while поломал сканнер

Comment: что  значит _while поломал сканнер_?  условие в цикле снова неправильное, масса заготовки `K` меньше массы слитка `N`, которая к тому же _не уменьшается_ в цикле.  К количеству монет нужно прибавлять _произведение_

Comment: Не рекомендуется закрывать `Scanner`, открытый на стандартном потоке ввода `System.in`, так как этот поток тоже будет закрыт.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = scn.nextInt();
        int K = scn.nextInt();
        int M = scn.nextInt();
        scn.close();
        int count = 0;

        while(N > M){
            int zagot = N / K;
            int ostatok = N - (zagot * K);
            for (int i = 0; i < zagot; i++) {
                int moneta = K / M;
                int ostatok2 = K - (moneta * M);
                N = ostatok + ostatok2;
                count += moneta;
            }
        }

Comment: большое спасибо! Времени не сталось, отправил такой код.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас получился бесконечный цикл. Цикл `for` имеет **три** необязательных (но очень нужных) параметра и в общем виде записывается так:

```
for(инициализация; условие работы; финальное выражение){
код цикла...
}
```

Где

`инициализация` - выражение или опредение переменной цикла. Обычно используется, чтоб инициализировать счетчик.

`условие работы` - выражение, которое проверяется на истенность на каждой итерации цикла. Если оно истенно, то цикл продолжается. Если его не прописать, то считается истенным всегда.

`финальное выражение` - выражение, которое выполняется в финале каждой итерации. Его связывают с условием работы, чтобы в нужный момент это условие стало ложным и программа завершила цикл.

`код цикла` - код который выполняется на каждой итерации цикла, пока `условие работы` истенно.

Если `финального выражения` нет - в конце итерации ничего не происходит, и истенное `условие работы` всегда будет истенным, а программа будет бесконечно выполнять код цикла, что и делает ваша программа. Добавьте `финальное выражение` `i = i+1` в ваш цикл или его сокращенную запись `i++`. Если остальной код написан правильно, все заработает.

P.S. Еще можно почитать про [постинкримент и преинкримент](https://user12vv.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/java-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-i-%D0%B8-i/) если Вам интересно.

Comment: не будет, условие можно изменить в теле цикла. Тем более что цикл можно прервать в любое время.